Since Sonoma my modified email signature are overwritten by apple mail
I was used to edit mail signature files in mac os but since Sonoma apple mail keeps overwriting the files althought i locked them. I changed the file on disked with bb-edit after having closed mail en unlocked the file using info-window. Locked the file again after modifying. Checking file afterwards everything okay. But after opening Apple Mail the previous version shows up and the mailsignature-file gets 'updated'.
So, how can I edit signature files outside of Mail?

@SteveChambers Are you mixing up Sonoma and Sequoia?

Theo, how did you edit signature files, via Mail or directly on disk? If directly on disk, is Mail open while you edit the file?

@SteveChambers - Thank you Steve for your reply - OS 14.5 - But I was helping a cliënt with an OS from 2020 and we encountered the same problem.

@nohillside - thank you for replying - I changed the file on disked with bb-edit after having closed mail en unlocked the file using info-window. Locked the file again after modifying. Checking file afterwards everything okay. But after opening Apple Mail the previous version shows up and the mailsignature-file gets 'updated'.

Is there a specific reason you don‘t edit the signatures within Mail?

@nohillside: yes, sorry ADD moment...

@nohillside - i have several reason. The most important, i would like the signature to behave responsive

Maybe you can use AppleScript to update the signature, so Mail is aware of the changes.
